# Iterating through a class vector causing problems

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

my program is trying to create a new account and compare the username against what I have inside my database. 1 from user input, and the other from a vector. I have to iterate through the vector and compare the 2 strings. But for some unknown reason, it only compares the FIRST value instead of comparing all the values inside the vector.

This is my code:
My LoginAcc.cpp

```
class AccountInfo {
public:
string username;
string password;
string type;
}; 

bool LoginAcc::checkAccountNameValid(string username) {
vector <AccountInfo> accInfo;
AccountInfo user;

ifstream UserDatabase("UserDatabase.txt");
string line = "";

while (getline(UserDatabase,line)) {
    stringstream linestream(line);

    getline(linestream,user.username,':');

    accInfo.push_back(user);
}

UserDatabase.close();

for(vector<AccountInfo>::iterator itr = accInfo.begin(); itr != accInfo.end(); ++itr) {
    if (username.compare((*itr).username) != 0)
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
}
```

My main.cpp

```
        case 'n':
        while (!flag) {
            cout << "Please enter a username with 8 characters. " << endl;
            cout << "Username : ";
            cin >> username;
            if (username.length() != 8) {
                cout << "Username does not meet the requirements" << endl;
                cout << "Username : ";
                cin >> username;
            }
            else {
                valid = login.checkAccountNameValid(username);
                if (valid == true) {
                    cout << "Please enter a password with 8 characters." << endl;
                    cout << "Password : " << endl;
                    cin >> password;
                    cout << "1. Student" << endl;
                    cout << "2. Lecturer" << endl;
                    cout << "3. Admin" << endl;
                    cout << "Please choose the category you belong to : ";
                    cin >> category;
                    login.createNewAcc(username,password,category);
                }
                else {
                    cout << "Username has been taken. Please choose another. " << endl;
                    cout << "Username : ";
                    cin >> username;
                }
            }
        }
        break;
```

I have a feeling its something wrong with my logic inside my 'checkAccountNameValid' method.
Can anyone give suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: You only evaluate one item in your Vector, you either return *true* or *false* on the first item. This is probably *not* what you intended.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg What I'm trying to do is that when the user inputs a username, I will compare it against the list of usernames that I already have in my database. Then if the user-input username is not found in the database, which means that the username is valid for the user to use.

Comment: Okay, but then you should return false in the loop if a match is found, and return true after loop when you know a match is not found.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Ur return true after loop refers to after the for-loop?

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Oh i understand what you mean. Then what should I do to make it run through the entire vector?

Comment: @JoelSeah Only return on the `true` case, then after your loop you can just say `return false` because you didn't find what you were looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(vector<AccountInfo>::iterator itr = accInfo.begin(); itr != accInfo.end(); ++itr) 
{
    if (username.compare((*itr).username) != 0)
        return true;
}
return false;
```

wait with returning `false`.

I also think you might have `!= 0` reversed: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/compare.

Another way to arrange the code might give you more clue as to how this works:

```
bool found = false;
for(auto itr = accInfo.begin(); itr != accInfo.end(); ++itr) 
{
    if (username.compare(itr->username) == 0)
        found = true;
}
return found;
```

A more modern approach would be

```
bool found = std::find_if(accInfo.begin(), accInfo.end(), 
   [] (AccountInfo const& ai) { return username == ai.username; });
```

Or indeed, use a datastructure that facilitates lookup, like `std::map` as shown in the other answer

Comment: Not gonna ranged for?

Comment: No, I'm not. The OP has shown he's got a hard time understanding how this works (also see Lounge). Besides, the other answer shows a more sane approach using `std::map` already

Comment: @sehe I understand now. Its bcoz of the return value in the branches of if-else that makes it stop at the first item of the vector. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The inner loop returns to the caller regardless of the outcome. You should `return false` after the loop completes.

Also, don't use `username.compare((*itr).username) != 0`. It's confusing (probably why you got it wrong (it should have been `== 0`)) and you can just use the equality operator: `username == itr->username`, which is well-defined for `std::string` (in case you were worried about the whole, "Don't compare `char *` using equality!" thing).

But what you really should do is store the data in a map keyed on username and do a direct lookup:

```
std::map<std::string, AccountInfo> accInfo;
⋮
return accInfo.find(username) != accInfo.end();
```

Comment: Return false of the loop completes? What to you mean by that?

Comment: @JoelSeah: I wrote "… *after* the loop completes".